# unit tests and logging

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have a couple of classes: *StateProcessor* and *State*.
I want to write a test for the method *StateProcessor.process(State)*.
The logic of this method is pretty simple, but it contains a lot of logging messages.

```
logger.info(state.getSourse().toString());
if (state.getTarget() == Target.A) {
 logger.info(state.getCreationTime());
 service.doSmth(state);
} else {
 logger.info(state.getTagret().getName());
 service.doOtherStff(state);
}
```

I don't want to pass the real *State* instance to the *process* method because this class is really complicated and it takes a lot of lines of code to build it. So, I want to pass mock object created with Mockito. According to the main logic, I need to mock only getTarget() method. But the execution will fail with NPE at *state.getTagret().getName()* and at  *state.getSourse().toString()*. But I don't like the idea of mocking all of these methods! They used only for logging. Also I don't want to fix my tests every time when I add some logging messages.

Logging is really useful there, so I don't want to remove it at all. But mocking the methods only for logging looks strange.

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can't you configure the test environment to cut off all `logger.info` messages, while you keep your dev showing them?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. logging is disabled at current moment. But I can't delete all these logger.info lines

Comment: I meant exactly what the first to answer states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Mocking [DEEP](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS). This will result in each method call returning a mock instead of `null` and prevent the NPEs.

```
 Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Works fine! I was looking for some magic and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a classic [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation, which is a textbook case for mocking problems.

As an alternative, consider logging the entire `State` object in one place--such as before the 'if' block--and overriding the toString() method to output everything you need to see.  Then you won't need to dereference each field and mock each method.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose all your logging calls inside an `if (!test) {}` block and inject the test attribute.

Or you could enclose them into an `if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {}` block and configure logging with info disabled, or inject a mock logger which returns false for `isInfoEnabled()`.

But logging is a key part of your code. So if you really want to test that it won't blow up in production, you should either test for nulls in your production code, or prove that these attributes may never return null, and inject a mock which doesn't return null either.

PS: do you really intend to keep properties named `tagret` and `sourse` in your code?

Comment: It's not bad idea to wrap the logging with "if". But this will mess the code. The code snippet is fabricated, so property names are not real.